# Complete table get updated instead of single row in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have Table named TableColumn. and I am getting ColumnListObj  with below django model api query.
Now I updated this object and save it.

```
ColumnListObj = TableColumn.objects.get(columnOne=One,columnTwo=Two)
ColumnListObj.column3 = 'SOME TEXT'
ColumnListObj.save()
```

**Accepted behavior** :

the one row which is being selected `(columnOne=One AND columnTwo=Two)` should get updated.

**Actual behavior**  :

Complete table with all `(columnTwo='Two')` get update.

NOTE:
1. ColumnOne and ColumnTwo are combined Primary key. means no duplicate.
2. I tried to debug and print the ColumnListObje after Get. its prints same desired row.

Schema for TableColumn (please dont get confuse by above dummy names)

```
class TableColumn(models.Model):
    table = models.ForeignKey('TableList',primary_key=True)
    table_column_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    current_column_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    column_description = models.CharField(max_length=1024, db_column='Column_Description',blank=True) 
class Meta:
    db_table = 'table_column'
```

Comment: i assume that to do what u want, django orm has to extract data from data db parse all data(which may be complicated may be not) find what was changed, build update query, and commit change to database. Much simple just to update and it will work same.

Comment: The code you have posted should only update a single row. But I'm confused about your mention on "combined primary key": Django doesn't support that. Please can you post your model code?

Comment: @DanielRoseman updated.. (please dont get confuse by above dummy names)

Comment: But that model isn't valid: Django only supports a single primary key. What version are you using?

Comment: 1.5.5 and it isn't giving any error.